# Gradle SSLHandShakeException while running spring boot application

Tags: spring-boot, gradle

I am trying to run spring boot project with below command but I am getting ssl handshake issue.

cmd>..\gradlew bootrun

Downloading https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-4.1-bin.zip

Exception in thread "main" javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target

I was referring http://www.jyothis.co.in/2011/11/12/javax-net-ssl-sslhandshakeexception/ and this is asking to install certificate from browser. I checked by copying the url in IE but it is missing certificate so I am not able to install it. Please guide me on how I could remove this error.

Thank you

Comment: Are you behind a proxy?

Comment: Not sure, but I found workaround. I am starting service manually by executing jar file from command prompt